# operator precedence in java - getting the wrong output

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

This is my code so far

```
public class Test1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = 13 - 3 * 6 / 4 % 3;
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

The output i am getting in 12, but is it not suppose to be -13?

Comment: Why should it be `-13`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis -3 * 6 is -18, -18 / 4 is -4 (it is int so it chops off the decimal part). -4 % 3 is -1, -1 * 13 is -13 is it not?

Comment: Seriously, if you think the operator precedence is wrong, at least specify how you think the precedence should be...

Comment: Why `-3`? This is not a unary `-`.

Comment: @popovitsj i did in the comment for some reason it wasnt letting me put it in the OP

Comment: - has the lowest precendence, so that's where your reasoning is off

Comment: the output should be 12.87. But because you use an integer you get only 12.

Comment: @popovitsj OHH wow i am so dumb lol i thought it was -3 * 6 since multiplication takes precedence but it shoulda just been 3 ty

Answer (score 2):

If we add clarifying parentheses, the expression becomes:

```
13 - ((3 * 6 / 4) % 3);
```

Due to integer division, the result of the division becomes 4.
Then the modulo results in 1.
So the final result is 12.